# Does MSI installer exist for Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, reportviewer2008

I'm trying to embed Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 to my installer package on InstallShield.

It accepts a Chained msi, but I was able only to find .exe and not a .msi version for ReportViewer.

Does anyone know if is there a way to find this ReportViewer.msi or convert the ReportViewer.exe to ReportViewer.msi?

thank you

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cc96c246-61e5-4d9e-bb5f-416d75a1b9ef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our team handled this by creating a setup prerequisite for Report Viewer using InstallShield.  We weren't able to find an msi for it, either, but found that the setup prerequisite was a better approach for us.